# Grails 3.2.11 plugin bintrayUpload missing grails-plugin.xml

Tags: grails, bintray

I follow the grails 3 plugin tutorial. I create a project:
https://github.com/fabiooshiro/no-surprises

```
$ gradle bintrayUpload
> Configure project :
Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but this build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source set. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0
        at build_84d0cz3ffyc3w9ul7qh3qjt2t.run(/home/ivt/investtools/no-surprises/build.gradle:17)
The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
        at build_84d0cz3ffyc3w9ul7qh3qjt2t.run(/home/ivt/investtools/no-surprises/build.gradle:17)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'mavenLocal'
   > Invalid publication 'maven': artifact file does not exist: '/home/ivt/investtools/no-surprises/build/classes/java/main/META-INF/grails-plugin.xml'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
11 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 9 up-to-date
```

Comment: You should use the `gradlew` script that is in that repo instead of the `gradle` you have on your `PATH`.  `./gradlew bintrayUpload`

Comment: bintrayUpload does not publish to Maven local on one's own computer.  The code above says clearly: Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal'. I have exactly the same problems when running 'grails install' on a plugin I created.  Even if I create the missing path, 'build/classes/java/main/META-INF/grails-plugin.xml' by copying what's in the Groovy part of the path, the command deletes that path before reading it.  It is now early December.  Seems this problem has existed for 5 months.